# In Internet Explorer 9, how can I view "browsing history" in chronological order?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I would like to trace my steps in time, like I can in Google Chrome. IE9 does not seem to do this... Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Under History, select "View By Order Visited Today" from the dropdown menu. That should give you the websites you visited in chronological order, though only for the current day.

Comment: But I need to further back in time :-(

Comment: I don't think that's possible in IE, sorry.